# ELM327 throws STOPPED massage no certain devices

Tags: java, android

I've got a weird problem!
I'm creating an Android app to run ELM327 bluetooth adapter. And it works fine on some devices without any issues and does not work on others. 
For example the app works on Samsung galaxy S6 and doesn't work on Galaxy TAB A6.

When I'm saying it doesn't work, it actually works but the ELM327 throws STOPPED messages in response...

```
 It's either one STOPPED >
        or with the answer..
      50 92 STOPPED >
```

It is happening not because of the ELM327. Why? Because I test them all like  3 different adapters and them all doing the same thing...
And it happening very unstable like once it will go with no problem the next you see the STOPPED massage.  `

```
void write(String income) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(income.getBytes());
            mmOutStream.write(13);
            mmOutStream.write(10);
            mmOutStream.flush();
            mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, income).sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.getStackTraceString(e);
        }
}
```

So by ELM manual ELM send this massage in the case when you sending an char when ELM doing something. Im defiantly not I know Im waiting for the promt char ">" in my code.. 
    So it's galaxy Tab bluetooth sends some kinda chars maybe a ping or something well it's breaks my head. But what I found out is:
     If I put delay in response then it works more stable..I see the stopped massage less...
    if I do like that:

```
mmOutStream.write(income.getBytes());
SystemClock.sleep(50);
mmOutStream.write(13);
mmOutStream.write(10);
mmOutStream.flush();
```

If I do like that I see the stopped massage even more:

```
mmOutStream.write(income.getBytes());
SystemClock.sleep(25);
mmOutStream.write(13);
SystemClock.sleep(25);
mmOutStream.write(10);
mmOutStream.flush();`
```

So it all probably not because of Im not waiting for the promt char but because of how the massage sent to a device. The are probably different delays between chars in the massage.  Well it's all very weird.

[The ELM manual saying abot STOPPED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgdhr.png)

Comment: I think if I some how  can put some delay in between the actual chars while I sending a massage it should fix my problem.. I think The Tab's Bluetooth sends the chars too fast.. So the atcual massage sends in "mmOutStream.write(income.getBytes());" The "income" length anywhere from 2 HEX to 7 HEX like this 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Samsung galaxy TAB A6 has an issue with it's Bluetooth module or something it works very unstable and unpredictable... No logic explanation how it transmits data.
enter code here

```
void write(String income) {
        byte Tray [] = income.getBytes();
        try {

            for(int i= 0; i< Tray.length; i++ ){
                mmOutStream.write(Tra[i]);
                SystemClock.sleep(10);
            }
            SystemClock.sleep(10);
            mmOutStream.write(13);
           // SystemClock.sleep(5);
            mmOutStream.write(10);
            mmOutStream.flush();

            mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, income).sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.getStackTraceString(e);
        }
}
```

If I do this way it became more stable and sometimes you can get satisfied result. But not the a 100% though.